# How to decode data from abi.encodeWithSignature?

Tags: solidity, abiencoderv2

How can I get decode data from my method abi.encodeWithSignature ?

```
contract Store {

    function set(address contractAddress, string memory value) public {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = address(contractAddress).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("set(string)", value));
        require(success, "Failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

abi.decode worked on me

```
uint256[] memory nfts = new uint256[](ownedAmount);

    (bool success, bytes memory result) = address(mainContractAddress).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("walletOfOwner(address)", msg.sender));
    require(success, "Failed to get owned ids...");
    nfts = abi.decode(result, (uint256[]));
```